# Update global variable from jquery nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, nested

I have a problem with this piece of code:

```js
var elements;
var current = 100;

$(document).ready(function() {
        elements =  = $('.slide').length;
        iterate();
});

function iterate() {
        $('.slide').eq(current).hide().queue(
                function() {
                        if (++current >= elements) { current = 0; }
                        $('.slide').eq(current).show();
                        $(this).dequeue();
                }
        );

        // Call this function again after the specified duration
        setTimeout(iterate, 1000);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate all elements with 'slide' class but I have a problem updating 'current' variable. Its value is always 0. How can I modify a global variable from inside a nested jquery function?

Comment: try removing the var keyword in the first line

Comment: What is the value of `elements`? And why use `arguments.callee` instead of `iterate`?

Comment: `console.log()` the value of `current` inside of your function's queue function.

Comment: @karancan That doesn't work :(

Comment: elements is a bad name, it says nothing about it being a length value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this line is invoked before the DOM is ready, `.length` is `0`:

```
var elements = $('.slide').length;
```

Which means the condition for this `if` will always be `true`:

```
if (++current >= elements) { current = 0; }
```

You can fix it like this:

```
var elements;
var current = 100;

$(document).ready(function() {
    elements = $('.slide').length;
    iterate();
});
```

Also, this is a little bit of an odd use of `.queue()`. There's nothing that needs queueing.

I'd rework it like this:

```
function iterate() {
    var slide = $('.slide').eq(current).hide();
    if (++current >= elements) { current = 0; }
    $('.slide').eq(current).show();

    // Call this function again after the specified duration
    setTimeout(iterate, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @epascarello: Just upadated. :-)

Comment: @user1689607 Yes, stupid mistake. I've set the variable inside the ready function but the result is the same. The variable is never updated inside the nested function.

Comment: @user1689607 Thanks for your edit. The problem seems to be that the queued function is never called. I was using this because I wanted to show the next element after hide the current one. How could I do this?

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía: You don't have any animations that would prevent this. If you do have an animation for the `.hide()`, then pass a callback function, and show the next element from within the callback.