# Why isn't the variable inside the function updated? (Scope, JQuery)

Tags: jquery, scope

I have multiple buttons for setting or changing an image.
I looked around at questions like this one: [Update global variable from jquery nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944141/update-global-variable-from-jquery-nested-function), but I'm not able to translate what I find into how it's relevant in this case.  =/

**Trying to do this:**
My buttons can have one out of two classes (custom-meta-img-add, custom-meta-img-change). When I click one with class -add I'm creating an image, if I'm clicking -change, I'm then updating the src of the related image.

**Question**: the second time I click a button, the second "console.log(button);" shows me the first button I clicked on.

```
$('body').on('click', '.custom-meta-img-add, .custom-meta-img-change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        console.log(button);

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }
        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            console.log(button);
        });
        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();
    })
```

How would you try to work this out? The first console.log(button) correctly shows me the button I click on each time.

Comment: Second `console.log(button);` located in event handler, which attached only if uploader object isn't created, i.e. only on first click. Thus, it will log only button, on which you clicked first.

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the value of what button was clicked inside the custom_uploader on each click? I mean, is there a way prefered to creating a new uploader on each click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to solve this is, as @Comet said, to take `var button;` out of `.on('click'` event and place it before the event. Then click handler will reassign `button` variable each time triggered, instead of creating new button variable, and `select` handler will correctly display clicked button. This doesn't mean making it global, just put it in outside scope, i.e. document.ready handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....
    var button;
    $('body').on('click', '.custom-meta-img-add, .custom-meta-img-change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        button = $(this);
        console.log(button);

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }
        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
               text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            console.log(button);
        });
        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();
    });
    ....
});
```

Of course, in this case better to `rename` button to something more specific, like `metaImgButton` or something. But having one more variable is surely better then recreating custom uploader each click.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to solve your problem

1. take  `var button;` out of `.on` event and place it before the event
2. assign `button = $(this);` as usual, just skip the `var` so that the global variable  `button` is assigned the value `$(this)`.

This will solve your problem because the variable button will be holding exactly which button is clicked.

Comment: (It is currently outside the .on('select') ) I don't want to make it global, this is part of a much bigger system. It does change correctly on every click, it's the custom_uploader that doesn't pick up on the changed button.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there must be a better way to do this. I'll solve this for now by **removing**

```
 //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
 if (custom_uploader) {
    custom_uploader.open();
    return;
 }
```

As that initiates the on select setting for each click, and thus it uses the correct button. I'll look back now and the through out today & tomorrow for a better(?) answer. :)

Cred to @berrunder.